# How to convert SVG path data into usable D3 data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Trying to get my head around D3 and I need to convert the somewhat confusing and complex SVG path data into simple numbers that D3 can understand for it to replicate the path. I have manually created an SVG in illustrator:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="558.79" height="291.94" viewBox="0 0 558.79 291.94">
  <title>templatetest</title>
  <path d="M1.48,291.72l3.83-26.14c1.05-7.21,1.83-14.42,2.52-21.71.07-.81.61-1.92,1.35-1.57a1.33,1.33,0,0,1,.55,1c1.26,6.15,1.27,15.59,4.86,20.88.86.6,1.84-.63,2.08-1.66,1.54-6.47,1-14.11,1.57-20.77.7-8,1.45-15.89,2.06-23.85.07-.88.37-2,1.25-2s1.22.76,1.34,1.48a5.61,5.61,0,0,0,.45,2.14,2.25,2.25,0,0,0,3.16.3,5.74,5.74,0,0,0,1.78-3c3.34-10.81,2.52-24.11,3.33-35.36Q33,162.44,34,143.49a1.59,1.59,0,0,1,.49-1.31c.88-.59,1.72.79,1.88,1.82,1.63,10.25,3.14,20.45,5.66,30.52a14,14,0,0,0,2.52,5.88,3.64,3.64,0,0,0,1.91,1.28c4.41.94,7.09-8.48,7.61-11.41l5.59-31.63c1.49-8.48,1.1-17.91,4.51-25.94.15-.35.38-.76.76-.8s.76.39,1,.78c2.85,5.46,2.58,12,4,17.89.93,3.82,3.46,20.92,7.71,21.79,5,1,9.08-11.94,10.48-15.4a340,340,0,0,0,18.77-64C111,51,111.24,28.44,115,6.35a7.53,7.53,0,0,1,.93-2.92C117.17,1.49,120,1,122.08,2a8.86,8.86,0,0,1,3.57,3.38c3.92,6.06,5.48,14.66,7.52,21.55,2.49,8.47,4.82,17,7.62,25.36q7.69,23,16.52,45.64c1.62,4.15,3.89,8.85,8.25,9.77,2.72.58,5.51-.54,7.92-1.94,14-8.09,22.65-26,38.69-27.78,9-1,17.57,3.67,26,7.11s18.75,5.52,26,.1c4.05-3,6.32-7.79,8.44-12.37,2.86-6.19,5.68-12.39,8.53-18.58,2-4.35,3.93-8.72,5.76-13.18a4,4,0,0,1,1-1.61,2.73,2.73,0,0,1,3-.16,8,8,0,0,1,2.32,2c6.1,7,11.89,15,19.87,19.94,9.06,5.66,19.84,7.8,30.4,9.47A466.22,466.22,0,0,0,558.33,54.07" style="fill: none;stroke: #000;stroke-miterlimit: 10;stroke-width: 3px"/>
</svg>
```

Which for those curious looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to use D3 to draw this same path. So I need some way to convert the path data (d) into values that D3 can understand, stripped of all the M, C, L etc. Here is the D3 code:

```
var path = svg.append("path")
      .attr("d", line(data))
      .attr("id","myPath")
      .attr("stroke", "red")
      .attr("stroke-width", "2")
      .attr("fill", "none");
```

The data variable needs to be something like:

```
var data = [1.48, 291.72, 3.83, 26.14, 1.05, 7.21...etc];
```

The path animates in and works fine with a bunch of random numbers in the data array. I've spent quite a few hours on here trying various methods but ultimately, a lot of the questions asked so far seem to want to do more complex things than the (seemingly) simple extraction/conversion that I need to perform.

Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: why not set the `d` attribute equal to the string you have in the illustrator result for attribute `d`. 26.14 should be -26.14 in your data array

Comment: What is the end goal of this exercise? You could write a little parser that gobbles up the `d` string from your illustrator SVG and recreates the line using [d3-path](https://github.com/d3/d3-path) commands, but it seems like a lot of hard work when you could just put the string directly into the `d` attribute of the `path` element.

Comment: @rioV8 - in this use case, when the "d" attr is set using the line(data) function, the data is a set of comma separated numbers. I was hoping there was a way to automate getting to this stage as it's quite a big string!

Comment: @ialarmedalien - End goal will be to have multiple graph lines animate between each other. They will have different numbers of points, and to work with the paths this way I'll need to use pathInterpolation:

[link]https://bocoup.com/blog/improving-d3-path-animation

To do this, I need access to the numbers, stripped of the necessary letters -  the raw data of the hand drawn graph for use and manipulation in D3 (and any future ones I may need to hand draw, rather than being created with actual provided data)

Comment: In that case, write a little parser (or search online, because I'm sure someone has already written one) to extract the numbers from your SVG path string.

Comment: how do you expect that `line(data)` will add the correct path elements (MmLlCcQq...) if you only supply the points, which point is absolute and which is relative and what is the spline to use and how many points for this particular spline

Comment: the bocoup page must contain a path-d splitter because he shows the values of the current path in the animations

Comment: https://github.com/pbeshai/d3-interpolate-path/blob/master/src/split.js

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way:

```
   svg
.append('path')
.attr('width', '18px')
.attr('height', '18px')
.attr('fill', '#5160E8')
.attr('d', 'M35.526 3.14379C35.526 1.68981 34.7464 0.509094 33.7844 0.509094H1.97927C1.01718 0.509094 0.237671 1.68981 0.237671 3.14379V24.2201C0.237671 25.6741 1.01718 26.8545 1.97927 26.8545H12.2357L17.8818 35.6364L23.5279 26.8545H33.7844C34.7464 26.8545 35.526 25.6741 35.526 24.2201V3.14379Z');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).